# Solve overdetermined system with QR decomposition in Python

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares, qr-decomposition

I'm trying to solve an overdetermined system with QR decomposition and linalg.solve but the error I get is

*LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square*.

This happens when the R array is not square, right? The code looks like this

```
import numpy as np
import math as ma

A = np.random.rand(2,3)
b = np.random.rand(2,1) 
Q, R = np.linalg.qr(A)
Qb = np.matmul(Q.T,b)
x_qr = np.linalg.solve(R,Qb)
```

Is there a way to write this in a more efficient way for arbitrary A dimensions? If not, how do I make this code snippet work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is indeed that the matrix `R` is not square, probably because the system is overdetermined. You can try [`np.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) instead, finding the solution which minimizes the squared error (which should yield the exact solution if it exists).

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(2, 3)
b = np.random.rand(2, 1) 
x_qr = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b)[0]
```

Comment: One should compute `x_qr = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b)[0]` directly, without first computing the QR decomposition of `A` which is redundant and is already done by `lstsq`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call QR with the flag mode='reduced'. The default Q R matrices are returned as M x M and M x N, so if M is greater than N then your matrix R will be nonsquare. If you choose reduced (economic) mode your matrices will be M x N and N x N, in which case the solve routine will work fine.

However, you also have equations/unknowns backwards for an overdetermined system. Your code snippet should be

```
import numpy as np 

A = np.random.rand(3,2)
b = np.random.rand(3,1) 
Q, R = np.linalg.qr(A, mode='reduced')
#print(Q.shape, R.shape)
Qb = np.matmul(Q.T,b)
x_qr = np.linalg.solve(R,Qb)
```

As noted by other contributors, you could also call lstsq directly, but sometimes it is more convenient to have Q and R directly (e.g. if you are also planning on computing projection matrix).

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the documentation of [`numpy.linalg.solve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html):

> Computes the “exact” solution, x, of the well-determined, i.e., full rank, linear matrix equation ax = b.

Your system of equations is [underdetermined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underdetermined_system) not overdetermined. Notice that you have 3 variables in it and 2 equations, thus fewer equations than unknowns.

Also notice how it also mentions that in `numpy.linalg.solve(a,b)`, `a` must be an `MxM` matrix. The reason behind this is that solving the system of equations `Ax=b` involves computing the inverse of `A`, and only square matrices are invertible.

In these cases a common approach is to take the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, which will compute a best fit (least squares) solution of the system. So instead of trying to solve for the exact solution use [`numpy.linalg.lstsq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html):

```
x_qr = np.linalg.lstsq(R,Qb)
```

Answer (score 0):

For updated solution for the case solving multiple right hand sides for the same non square matrix:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

numRows = 500
numCols = 100
numIn   = 1000 #<! Number of inputs

mA = np.random.randn(numRows, numCols)
mB = np.random.randn(numRows, numIn)

mX = np.zeros(shape = (numCols, numIn))

mQ, mR = sp.linalg.qr(mA, mode = 'economic')

for ii in range(numIn):
    mX[:, ii] = sp.linalg.solve_triangular(mR, mQ.T @ mB[:, ii], check_finite = False)
```

This should be faster than calling higher level functions like `solve()` or `lstsq()`.